# Wiremock issue when upgrading to java 17

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

We have our application using Spring Boot 2.7 with Java 8. It's a restful service that uses JAX-RS with Jersey for implementation. I am now trying to move to Java 17 and the Application is working as expected but we have some junit test cases that use wiremock and they are failing. I tried to upgrade the version of Wiremock but still had no success. We are currently using com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.35.0. It's working completely fine with Java 8 but not with Java 17. I tried com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:3.0.0, com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:3.0.0 and all major versions from new packages like org.wiremock:wiremock:3.0.4.

I read there are issues due to javax/jakarta namespace change and using stand-alone package might help but in my case, I am getting errors with that as well. As I have not upgraded my spring boot version to 3 or above I am still using javax package.

After trying for many weeks I decided to upgrade to spring boot 3 and again after doing all the changes (Including changes related to jakarta namespace) everything started working and still wiremock dosn't. I again tried diffrent packages and versions of wiremock like 2.27.2, 3.0.4, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.3.0 with both normal as well as stand alone packages.

This is how we are mocking.

```java
public void stubDelete(String url, int status) {
        WireMock.stubFor(delete(urlEqualTo(url))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .withStatus(status))
            );
    }
```

I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@3fc064cb testClass = com.test.IntegrationTest, locations = [], classes = [com.test.Application], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["test"], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true", "server.port=0"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@23f5b5dc, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5db6b9cd, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@4dc27487, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@f58853c, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ce740854], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow
```

Can someone help me understand why we get this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow` that doesn't have anything to do with Jakarta afaik. Spring Boot 3 uses Jakarta, as long as you aren't using that it doesn't matter.

Comment: I already changed to the Jakarta namespace with Spring Boot 3

Comment: Not according to your question.

Comment: I have updated the details. I tried 2 things 1-  Java 17, Spring boot 2 with javax. 2- Java17 spring boot 3 with jakarta. In both case my application is working just junits that are related to wiremock are failing

Comment: Which is what I said that `Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow` it has nothing to do with JakartaEE / JavaEE. Either a wiremock version that isn't java17 compatible or something in your configuration.